# Is there a way to retrieve tree structure with break XML tree structure?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, tree, xml-parsing

I am trying to traverse XML file with many nested children. As I understand common XML structure have parent-> children-> many other children, etc...

What happens when this structure is not so strict and it was used some kind of linked list of nodes HEAD_NODE and NODE numbers. Where ancestors HEAD_NODE point to NODE of parent and that creates whole structure.

```
...            
           <AAA>
              <BB>
                <HEAD_NODE>         0</HEAD_NODE>
                <NODE>         1</NODE>
                <LVL>         1</LVL>
                ...
                <BB>
                  <HEAD_NODE>         1</HEAD_NODE>
                  <NODE>         2</NODE>
                  <LVL>         2</LVL>
                  ...
                  <BB>
                    <HEAD_NODE>         2</HEAD_NODE>
                    <NODE>         3</NODE>
            <LVL>         3</LVL>
                    ...
                   
                    <BB>
                      <HEAD_NODE>         3</HEAD_NODE>
                      <NODE>         4</NODE>
                      <LVL>         4</LVL>
                      ...
                      <BB>
                        <HEAD_NODE>         4</HEAD_NODE>
                        <NODE>         5</NODE>
                        <LVL>         5</LVL>
                        ...
            
                      <BB>
                      <HEAD_NODE>         3</HEAD_NODE>
                      <NODE>        17</NODE>
                      <LVL>         4</LVL>
                      ...
                      <BB>
                        <HEAD_NODE>        17</HEAD_NODE>
                        <NODE>        18</NODE>
                        <LVL>         5</LVL>
                        ...
                      </BB>
                      <BB>
                        <HEAD_NODE>        17</HEAD_NODE>
                        <NODE>        19</NODE>
                        <LVL>         5</LVL>
                        ...
                     <BB>
                      <HEAD_NODE>         3</HEAD_NODE>
                      <NODE>       145</NODE>
                      <LVL>         4</LVL>
                      
                      <BB>
                        <HEAD_NODE>       145</HEAD_NODE>
                        <NODE>       163</NODE>
                        <LVL>         5</LVL>
                        
                      </BB>
                      <BB>
                        <HEAD_NODE>       145</HEAD_NODE>
                        <NODE>       164</NODE>
                        <LVL>         5</LVL>
                        
                      </BB>
                      <BB>
                        <HEAD_NODE>       145</HEAD_NODE>
                        <NODE>       165</NODE>
                        <LVL>         5</LVL>
                        
                      </BB>
                      <BB>
                        <HEAD_NODE>       145</HEAD_NODE>
                        <NODE>       166</NODE>
                        <LVL>         5</LVL>
                        
                      </BB>
                      <BB>
                        <HEAD_NODE>       145</HEAD_NODE>
                        <NODE>       167</NODE>
                        <LVL>         5</LVL>
                        
                      </BB>
                      <BB>
                        <HEAD_NODE>       145</HEAD_NODE>
                        <NODE>       168</NODE>
                        <LVL>         5</LVL>
                        ...
                      </BB>
...
```

In some cases this structure corresponds to the XML structure, but in some cases it does not.

Using Xpath I was able to get the leaf nodes, basically the ones that should be at the end of these trees.

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

leaf_elements = root.xpath('//*[local-name()="BB"][not(.//*[local-name()="BB"])]/*[local-name()="HEAD_NODE"]')
```

And my question is how to go up and harvest all these trees in some meaningful way (All these nodes contains additional information, and also I would like to see that path).

Thanks for any hints.

### Update

I mixed `networkx` library and `lxml` and it returns better results. It is still not 100% solution but it is close to that

````py
from lxml import etree
import networkx as nx

# create empty graph
G = nx.DiGraph()

for head_node in root.xpath('//ns:HEAD_NODE', namespaces=ns):
    node_id = head_node.text.strip()
    
    G.add_node(head_node)
    
    for node in head_node.xpath('./following-sibling::ns:NODE', namespaces=ns):
        child_id = node.text.strip()
        G.add_edge(node_id, child_id)
    
# I can look for all these path
nx.shortest_path(G, source='0', target='442')```
````

Comment: If it has arbitrary connections between nodes it is called a "graph". There are many algorithms and libraries to traverse and manipulate graphs.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is a kind of graph, but should not xpath be able to read/load this as well ? Because when I use a naive solution (nested loops), the time consumption is too big and xpath with lxml is much faster.

Comment: Maybe an XPath specialist has some ideas but generally XPath was made for the XML **tree** structure.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will try to find some libraries for that. Do you have any recommendations ?

Comment: If you are not restricted to XML, there is https://networkx.org/

Comment: I've done this many times.  It is not the library, but the algorithm you use to parse the file.  You have a tree structure and need to parse the tree using recursion.  The results would be tree of objects.

Comment: If you knew XPath 3.1, or were prepared to learn it, this kind of thing is fairly easy in XPath version 3.1. You could use this library: https://pypi.org/project/saxonche/ to enable XPath 3.1 in Python. Using lxml you are restricted to XPath version 1.0, which is very dated and not expressive enough for your purpose. With XPath 1.0 you would need to write the graph traversal code in Python and use XPath only for lookups.